# Disable nagle's algorithm (TCP_NODELAY) using QWebSocket

Tags: qt, websocket, tcp

I am using a QWebSocket in a client application and I need to disable nagle's algorithm used in TCP.

Fortunately, QWebSocket seems to disable it by default : [QWebSocketImplementation](https://github.com/qt/qtwebsockets/blob/5.15.2/src/websockets/qwebsocket_p.cpp#L428), [LowDelayOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketOption-enum)

However, it does seems to have any effects on the TCP_NODELAY option. Using [knetstat](https://github.com/veithen/knetstat) to view the socket option I get this :

```
SO_REUSEADDR=0,SO_REUSEPORT=0,SO_KEEPALIVE=0,TCP_NODELAY=0,TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT=0
```

So it looks like the option is not actually set. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Depending on the operating system, you may have to e.g. run as root or something similar to set TCP_NODELAY